# GridView Delete Not Re-Binding

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a GridView with a delete template field:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCurrentDay" CssClass="gridview" OnRowCommand="gvCurrentDay_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="Client" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectTitle" HeaderText="Project" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeToAdd" HeaderText="Time Allocated" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imbDeleteRow" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/DeleteRed.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RecordID") %>' CommandName="Delete" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>    
</ContentTemplate>
```

The code runs when the button is pressed and the database entry is removed from the database, but the GridView is not rebinding, here is the code that controls the delete:

```
protected void gvCurrentDay_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int RecordID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        tdl objTdl = new tdl();
        objTdl.DeleteEntryForDay(RecordID);

        GetItineryForDay(Convert.ToDateTime(txtCalendar.Text));

        lblMessages.Text = "Entry removed";
    }
}
```

And here is the first part of the GetItineryForDay procedure:

```
protected void GetItineryForDay(DateTime SelectedDate)
{
    gvCurrentDay.DataSource = null;
    gvCurrentDay.DataBind();

    tdl objTdl = new tdl();
    DataTable dt = objTdl.GetUsersProjectTimeForDay(SelectedDate, Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["staffid"].Value));

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
        int TotalTime2 = Convert.ToInt32(row[7]);
        string TotalTime = row[7].ToString() + " minutes";

        gvCurrentDay.DataSource = dt;
        gvCurrentDay.DataBind();
```

Can you see from the code any reason why the GridView is not updating? The GridView sits in an UpdatePanel.

Comment: You are binding the drid only if `dt.Rows.Count` is greater than 0. Maybe in this case there are no rows that gets returned and hence the grid is not binding

Comment: Are you sure you are getting values into the DataTable dt? (I mean is the count more than 0)

Comment: Yes it is, there are 6 rows, depending on how many times you try the sample.

Comment: You should include more of the ASPX code.  You note that the GV is in an UpdatePanel - perhaps there's something about the way that panel is defined/configured which is causing the problem.

Comment: Added in the extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `"Delete"` as the `CommandName`, use something else, like `"ManualDelete"`. `"Delete"` is usually trapped by `RowDeleting` and `RowDeleted` events.

Alternatively, and since "the database entry is removed from the database", you could put your rebind code in the RowDeleted event.

```
protected void gvCurrentDay_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    GetItineryForDay(Convert.ToDateTime(txtCalendar.Text));
    lblMessages.Text = "Entry removed";
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, changing 'Delete' as the CommandName seemed to solve it!